# How can I properly assign a char* in c++?

Tags: c++, char, c-strings

My c++ code looks like this:

```
char* x;
    switch(i){ 
        case 0:
            x = '0';
        case 1:
            x = "1";
        ...}
```

I can't figure out how to make this work because for the first  `x = '0';`  the compiler complains with:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’
```

and for the second `x = "1";` the compiler complains with:

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

What should I do here? Am I going about this completely wrong?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to assign these values to a char* that I later use strcat() on.

Comment: Will `x` later be the first or 2nd arg to `strcat`? If it will be the first, you will very likely have another question after you get your answer to this one.

Comment: Ultimately, I just made everything `char` and then used `&x` in the strcat and it worked, thanks so much everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `case 0` you're trying to set `x` to a character (of type `char`), but in `case 1` you're trying to set `x` to a C string (of type `char const[2]`). It's the type of quotes that make a difference; single-quotes are for characters, and double quotes are for C-style strings.

If you're meaning to set it to a string both times, put double quotes around the `0` in `x = '0'`.

If you're meaning to set `x` to a character, use single quotes both times and dereference the pointer, like `*x`, so that it becomes `*x = '0'`, or `*x = '1'`, **or** change the type of `x` from `char*` (pointer to character) to `char` (character). Then you don't have to dereference it.<sup>1</sup>

Then again, if you are trying to set `x` to a string, it would be better to use a C++ string instead of a C string, with `std::string`. Then you'd do it with double quotes like a C string, but you'd get a bevvy of extra features like automatic memory management, bounds checking, and all the member functions that it has.

<sup>1</sup> As Nicolas Grebille pointed out: before doing that, make sure it points to a valid `char`, either using `new`:

```
char* x = new char;
```

or by creating a `char` on the stack:

```
char c;
char* x = &c;
```

**Important**:

If you're going to use a `char*` with `strcat` later (or with any function expecting a C-string), you **must** properly `NULL` terminate your buffer. So you need to do it either this way:

```
char x[2] = {}; // on the stack, filled with NULLs
                // use a bigger number if you need more space
```

or

```
char* x = new char[2]; // on the heap, use more than 2 if you're
                       // storing more than 1 character
x[1] = NULL; // set the last char to NULL
```

If you don't do that, you'll get garbage if you're unlucky or a segfault if you are lucky.

Then after you declare `x` as the above, you can do `*x = '0'` or whatever.

**If you decide to use `new[]`, make sure you deallocate the memory with a corresponding `delete[]`.**

Comment: I would add that to use `*x = '0'`, the declaration `char * x` is not enough (see other answers below).

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to popular belief, `char*` is not a string.  Use `std::string` instead.

```
#include <string>

std::string x;
switch(i){ 
    case 0:
        x = "0";
    case 1:
        x = "1";
    ...}
```

Comment: Nice rep count :) Also a string is what you call it. So `double` can be a string if we say so.

Comment: @Seth: hahaha same rep count!

Comment: I'll just add that, if you're not trying to store a string but rather a only a character, replacing `std::string` with `char` in this answer and double quotes with single quotes will also work.

Comment: @Seth: in `const char * x = "foo";`, `"foo"` is a string litteral, and `x` points to a block of bytes terminated by a 0 byte.  `x` is not a string, it is a pointer to a constant character array.  `std::string` provides real string operations.

Comment: Would love to do this, but afterwards to feed the x to the strcat.(nom nom nom) So  i need it to be a char*

Comment: @Andre meh, potayto potahto. It was a string in C, it's a C-string in C++. Because it's a sequence of characters.

Comment: @weezy are you sure you need to use `strcat` instead of just `operator+` of `std::string`? Or are you working with preexisting code you can't modify?

Comment: @Seth: I spent so many hours helping people debug code littered with `char[]` and `char*` and C-string errors all over the place that I've become highly irritated by the concept of people using `char*` as if it were `std::string`.  I resort to telling people a "C doesn't have strings, so 'C-strings' don't exist".

Comment: Perhaps you could eliminate the warning by simply adding a "const" to the declaration of x?  It's been a long time since I used pure C.

Comment: @Andre if you're lying to children, that's fine. As long as you don't really believe that :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use a char *, you need to allocate space for the string to be stored either by changing the declaration of x to something like:

```
char x[10]; // allocate a fixed 10-character buffer
```

or dynamically allocating the space on the heap:

```
x = new char[10]; // allocate a buffer that must be deleted later
```

then you can use:

```
strcpy(x, "1"); // Copy the character '1' followed by a null terminator
                // into the first two bytes of the buffer pointed to by x.
```

to copy the string "1" into the buffer pointed to by x.  If you use the second example, you must later:

```
delete x;
```

Of course if you really want to deal with strings there are better ways, and there are better ways to deal with individual characters as well (see other answers).

Answer (score 2):

It's more a remark that an answer, but you can get the chars `0`, `1`,... from the int with:

```
char x = '0' + i;
```

wich would avoid your switch statement (with `0 <= i <= 9` of course).

Comment: are you sure this works? It doesn't seem to be working for me, but the maybe I problem somewhere else.

Comment: @weezybizzle I am almost sure this should work, yes. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: it was further down in the program, I got it sorted out. Thanks for the nifty trick!

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a `char` *pointer*, not allocating any space, then trying to assign a character to it.

```
char x;
```

Would give you a variable of type `char`

```
char *x = new char[10];
```

would give you a pointer to 10 bytes of memory pointed at by a char pointer.

As noted by [André Caron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313063/andre-caron) above, since you're using c++ you really should be using an actual string to make your life easier

Comment: And make sure you properly NULL terminate the array after allocating it.

Answer (score 1):

First, please figure out a way that you can use `std::string`. If you continue on the path you have chosen, you will certainly create buggy programs.

Having said that, here is your answer: How you declare `x`, and how you assign to it, depends in large part upon how you later use it. Here is one example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int ac, char **av) {
  const char* x;      
  switch(ac) {
  case 0:
    x = "0";
    break;
  case 1:
    x = "1";
    break;
  default:
    x = "DANGER!";
    break;
  }
  printf("%s\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

In this first example, we set the pointer `x` to point to one of three possible const char arrays. We can read from those arrays later (as in the `printf` call), but we can never write to those arrays.

Alternatively, if you wish to create an array you can later write to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int ac, char **av) {
  char x[32]; // make sure this array is big enough!     

  switch(ac) {
  case 0:
    strcpy(x, "0");
    break;
  case 1:
    strcpy(x, "1");
    break;
  default:
    strcpy(x, "NOT 0 nor 1:");
    break;
  }

  strcat(x, ", see?");
  printf("%s\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

*EDIT*: Get rid of incorrect `const` from 2nd example.